# Invalid self-closing tag in svg

Tags: svg, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

In a vue.js (1.0.26) app, built with webpack (1.13.1) and vue-loader (8.5.3), 
There is a problem when importing a component which is just a part of a svg.

[here is a repo with this problem](https://github.com/francoisromain/vuejs-svg-test)

parent component:

```
<template>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1280 512">
        <axis-x></axis-x>
    </svg>
</template>

<script>
import axisX from './axis-x.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        axisX
    }
}
</script>
```

child component:

```
<template>
    <g>
        <line x1="1" y1="400" x2="1" y2="416" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />
        <text x="16" y="414" fill="black">1990</text>
    </g>
</template>

<script>
export default {
};
</script>
```

when webpack runs it makes the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/axis-x.vue
  2 |   <g>
  3 |   <line x1="1" y1="400" x2="1" y2="416" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />
    |   ^
  4 |   <text x="16" y="414" fill="black">1990</text>

Invalid self-closing tag: <line x1="1" y1="400" x2="1" y2="416" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1" />. 
This will be treated as the starting tag only in HTML5. Use <line></line> instead.
```

It looks like the loader interprets the svg part as invalid HTML.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Closing line works?

<line x1="1" y1="400" x2="1" y2="416" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1" ></line>

Comment: it does work… But is it still valid SVG?

Comment: yes, also you can put another elements http://stackoverflow.com/a/2529032/4690316

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will go like that for now, but still, I would like to find a way to use self-closing svg elements.

Answer (score 0):

This warning comes from [`vue-template-validator`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-template-validator/blob/master/lib/rules/self-closing-tag.js). Unfortunately it has no configuration options.

I'm not sure, but it seems that you can turn it off by simply adding `lang="html"` attribute to the `template` element ([`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/blob/master/lib/parser.js#L92) uses it only when no `lang` attribute was specified). In that case `vue-loader` will use `html-loader` without validation.

Answer (score 0):

After cloning your application and running it gave me the same error and it was quite clear that you can you self closing line tag in html5 so just by using

```
<line x1="1" y1="400" x2="1" y2="416" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1" ></line>
```

Resolved the problem